# No error when creating zip, but it doesn't get created inside directory

Tags: php

I wrote this code to create a ZIP file of my uploaded attachment, wp  application has an option to uploads pdf , those upload pdf will stored under upload directory , i got the result success with no error's but still zip is not get created inside the directory server  . Here's the code:

```
    // Code for Getting links (Path)of Attachements 
     $list = array();
// $count = 1;
foreach($applicants as $key=>$val) {
 $cat_id =explode("-", $key);   
  foreach($val as $appkey=>$appval) { 
      // if(($appval['name'])=='Navn') {
      //   $names = $count . '_' . $cat_id[1] . '_' .   stripslashes($appval['value']) ;       
      // }
      if(($appval['name']) == ' (PDF)') {
        $attach = stripslashes($appval['value']) ;
        $list[] = $cat_id[0].'-'. $cat_id[1].'/' . $attach; // Attaching ID and Category to attachement file name
      }
  }
 // $count++;   
 } 

$paths = array();
foreach ($list as $list) {
$data = explode('/',$list);

$pdfpath='../../' . $data[7] . '/' . $data[8] . '/' . $data[9] . '/' . $data[10];
$name=(string)$data[0] . '_' . $data[10];

$paths[] = $pdfpath."*".$name; 
}

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$rand = rand(0,5000);
// Generating random file name for zipcode
if ($zip->open($rand . 'appl_attachments.zip',  ZipArchive::CREATE)) {

 // add files to zip from the path i.e uplaods(Folder) if file exists
  foreach ($paths as  $value ) { 
  $path=explode("*", $value);
  if(file_exists($path[0])) {
    $zip->addFile($path[0],$path[1]);
  }     
  }
  $zip->close();
```

Comment: You know, this is *probably* gonna sound a little bit crazy from the coding point of view, but it actually solved my problem once... try using `$k=>$value` inside foreach and then use `$value[$k]` inside your `explode()`. It might not give you any errors but that doesn't mean that your `if` statement inside your `foreach` is actually returning `true`. In any case, just echo each variable to see if they're actually what you're expecting them to be.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I have tested and seems same result , Better i am adding my whole zip creation file over here :
https://github.com/karthick-m-ica/backend/blob/master/zip.php
Please check this if you go any solution for this issue . 
Additional may be we have any file permission or configuration issue on server ?

Comment: You are welcome. If your files are 0644 and folders are 0755 by default, I think it's all ok with file permissions. But anyway, did you echo each `$path[0]` and `$path[1]` to see if they actually are what you want them to be? I'll check your file.

Comment: yep path 1 has return the cat value and path 0 has the uploaded path directory, 
even i have set file permission to 777 and enable the zip and zlib lib and i am using ubuntu , struggling out on this for a long time , 
Just i am getting data form db and zip those seems not working .

Comment: FYI : I have other three option by using this same  catagory option  one is export my form data's  in pdf and csv  and attachmet as zip,  the both thing works fine  but only zip of the attachment is not creating

Comment: output of print $path ; Array ( [0] => ../../uploads/2015/eer-RJU5YS_MAD-CPH.pdf [1] => 292-E_eer-RJU5YS_MAD-CPH.pdf )

Comment: Is `file_exists()` returning true? Even if you knew that the file does exist, is it actually returning true?..... Also, did you try using an absolute path when creating the ZIP file in the `open()` function? Maybe try looking for the created file in another directory.

Comment: No error on path , my absolute path is showing up,  Then only issue is on zip creation ,  Is there any sample file i can test zip creation is working in my server

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a fix on the issue , update the changes on the pdf path .
Here is the changes on the code :

```
$paths = array(); 
foreach ($list as $list) {
$data = explode('/',$list);

$pdfpath='../../' . $data[6] . '/'. $data[7] . '/' . $data[8] . '/' . $data[9] ;
$name=$data[9];
```

Comment: Alright, since I don't know your algorithm I'd never figured that one out haha. But I'm glad you found your answer. Good luck now!